# What does it mean by "(to) question the need for something" has used in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I was faced with this part: **never question the need for its existence** when reading some book about Programming Language. The Whole sentence was:

> The use of the `null value` is so common, in so many languages, "that
> many experienced  programmers **never question the need for its
> existence**". But there are many scenarios where  we could write better,
> simpler code if a variable is not allowed to have a null value

Would anybody explain to me that what the bold section exactly says?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To question something means to have doubts about something.

> to express doubts about the value or truth of something:
>
> > I questioned the wisdom of taking so many pills.

([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/question))

The thing that they may have doubts about is "the need for the existence of the null value".

If they "never question the need..." this means that they never have doubts about the need for the null value.

Which means they *are certain that the null value needs to exist*.

Comment: Thank you very much.